# How to Delay Complete-BitsTransfer until Transfer Complete?

Tags: powershell, file-transfer, microsoft-bits

The following bits transfer starts a bunch of bits jobs, which work perfectly when I manually complete the transfer later: `Get-BitsTransfer | Complete-BitsTransfer`

My attempt to script a delay before complete is not working.  The `While` is not processed, or perhaps it's processed before the transfer jobs even start.

```
loop starts many jobs...
    $job = Start-BitsTransfer -Source $fileUrl -Destination $fileDest -Asynchronous
...end loop

While ($job.JobState -eq "Transferring") {
    Sleep -Seconds 1
}

Get-BitsTransfer | Complete-BitsTransfer
```

Any suggestion how to permit `-Asynchronous` jobs a chance to load before executing complete?

After I added a 1-second delay before the wait, the script above waits. Seems hacky.

Comment: You are probably waiting in While loop only for "last package" of bittransfers created by previous loop. Could you post code of the loop which creates BitTransfers?

Answer (score 0):

cezarypiatek deserves this answer:

Problem is the While loop checking only the last package.  Code corrected to:

```
$job - @()
loop starts many jobs...
    $job += Start-BitsTransfer -Source $fileUrl -Destination $fileDest -Asynchronous
...end loop

While ($job | Where-Object{$job.JobState -eq "Transferring"}) {
    Sleep -Seconds 1
}

Get-BitsTransfer | Complete-BitsTransfer
```